# Prevent Windows 7 from enabling power saving on USB 3.0 hub

Tags: windows-7, usb, power-management

I have installed a USB 3.0 hub on my desktop computer.

I use it to connect an external USB 3.0 disk for backup purposes, and I have a problem: Windows 7 enables by default power saving for said hub, which causes the disk to disconnect during intense I/O operations (e.g. my scheduled backup at 8 p.m.).

I can disable this setting by doing the following:
Go to the Device Manager > Right click on the hub > Properties > Power management > Uncheck *Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power*

Too bad, every time I restart the computer, the box is checked again. Is there a way to disable this setting permanently?

**EDIT**: I edited my question with the actual English names for the settings above (it wasn't very clear before).

***EDIT***: [Peter Fitzgerald](https://superuser.com/users/147976/peter-fitzgerald)'s [answer](https://superuser.com/a/750013/288739) describes exactly what I've been doing so far. Every time I reboot the checkbox is marked again, I'm looking for a way to disable it permanently.

***EDIT***: after reading [Synetech](https://superuser.com/users/3279/synetech)'s [answer](https://superuser.com/a/768831/288739), I was able to track down the registry entry that is changed when I change the setting, which is:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\FLUSB\ROOT_HUB_FL30\5&f0b5d82&1\Device Parameters\WDF\IdleInWorkingState (DWORD)
```

This key is changed by the Management Console whenever I unset the checkbox, and also when I deactivate & reactivate the device by process System. Too bad, any setting in the authorizations is misteriously ignored, and even by denying every privilege to everyone the key is always set to 1.

I tried searching online, and I found [this Microsoft guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544757%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Trying to set every single key they described did not help, it seems these keys are ignored. I even tried to copy the right path for the keys from existing *.INF* found online (which  keys to put under `/WDF` and which keys to put under the parent), like [this](http://delivery.stpb.net/!!!drivers/windows7/Apple%20iPod/wpdmtp.inf), but I got nothing.

Other useful information:

- under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\FLUSB\ROOT_HUB_FL30\`, I also have these two voices: `5&f0b5d82&0` and `5&21f33a01&0`, which seems to mirror the configuration of the key above.
  The only `IdleInWorkingState` changing, though, is the one described above.
- when I manually edit the register, the value of the checkbox in the Device Manager doesn't change, it has to be cached somewhere.

Comment: Is the [USB selective suspend setting](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/147369-usb-selective-suspend-turn-off.html) enabled?

Comment: @and31415: no, it is not. I had to disable that as well a quite ago, but it stays that way after reboot.

Comment: Is this set to Disabled : Control Panel -> Power Options -> Change plan settings -> Change advanced power settings -> USB settings -> USB selective suspend setting.

Comment: @harrymc, if you read the 2 comments above you'll see that I've already disabled it.

Comment: What make is your USB3? Mine doesn't have a "Power management" tab at all and it never powers off completely.

Comment: @harrymc, it is listed as Fresco Logic xHCI(USB3) Root Hub. It is an internal hub that came with its own driver CD.

Comment: Have a look at [this thread](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19495043.aspx). The supplied driver might be bad. I found two drivers: [3.5.36.0](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=32V81) and [3.5.93.0](http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/MOTHERBOARD/Others/Fresco-Logic-USB-30-Driver-35930.shtml) mentioned in the thread and more are to be found on the Internet. What version is your driver and what model your computer?

Comment: @harrymc, that was a good attempt: I updated my driver from 3.5.100.0 to 3.5.107.0 and I was really hoping it would work. Unfortunately, it did not.

Comment: You might try an earlier driver, sometimes it helps.

Comment: @harrymc thanks for the advice, but I keep that as the last resort, as I would have to install outdated software which I can't find on the official site anymore, and sure isn't appealing. I prefer to give a shot to other methods first, but I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: An outdated driver is not dangerous, and in any case going back to the most recent one is easy enough. But it would be a good test.

Comment: `when I manually edit the register, the value of the checkbox in the Device Manager doesn't change, it has to be cached somewhere.` Yes, in memory. It reads it once during boot-up while it is initializing hardware, and perhaps again whenever the device is disabled then re-enabled. Otherwise, it treats the registry value as write-only during normal operation (it does not expect it to change, manually, only using the official interface).

Comment: @Synetech: yes, but still on reboot nothing changes; also, the whole permissions on registry thing doesn't work (it seems permissions are completely ignored).

Comment: @harrymc, my fear was about the fact that I would have to download the driver from a place different from the official site. But now I might try it, every other possible rational solution has not worked.

Comment: I have added the two drivers to my answer. It might be better to install them and use the procedure that I outlined.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who helped me, but I got tired of wasting time on Windows and hacked the problem away with a script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since none of the other solutions have worked, I solved with the following workaround:

### Powershell script to disable the setting

Editing a script found on the Internet, I built this:

**C:\powerMgmt.ps1**

```
$hubs = Get-WmiObject Win32_USBHub
$powerMgmt = Get-WmiObject MSPower_DeviceEnable -Namespace root\wmi | where {$_.InstanceName.Contains($hubs.PNPDeviceID)}

foreach ($p in $powerMgmt)
{
    $p.Enable = $False
    $p.psbase.Put()
}
```

### Executing at startup with elevated privileges

The above script requires elevated privileges, so I created a task in the Task Scheduler of Windows 7 to run the following script (as user Administrator) when I login with my user:

**C:\powerMgmt.cmd**

```
powershell -file C:\powerMgmt.ps1
```

This whole thing is a bit of a hack; it's not elegant and it doesn't help me understand the problem, but it solves it.

Answer (score 7):

## Power Requirements

> I have installed a USB 3.0 hub on my desktop computer. I use it to connect an external USB 3.0 disk for backup purposes, and I have a problem: Windows 7 enables by default power saving for said hub, which causes the disk to disconnect during intense I/O operations

Are you sure the drive is shutting down to power-management and not simply because it is trying to draw too much power? You can check the power draw on your USB hub via the *Device Manager* (figures 1 and 2). Verify that the power that the hub can provide **per port** is sufficient for the external drive. If not, you may be able to use a USB Y-adapter (figures 3 and 4) to draw power from two ports. (High-draw external drives usually come with a Y-adapter specifically for this purpose, so double-check the box and manual.)

## Tracking Down the Disease

> I can disable this setting by doing the following:
Go to the Device Manager > Right click on the hub > Properties > Power management > Uncheck Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power
>
> Too bad, every time I restart the computer, the box is checked again. Is there a way to disable this setting permanently?

If disabling that setting does actually solve the problem at hand, then the problem now is  getting it to stick and not revert. One option is to use something like [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) with a filter set to the relevant registry entry ([`HcDisableSelectiveSuspend`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/usb-selective-suspend#enabling-selective-suspend)) to see what program changes it so that the option is turned off (it should be set to `1` to *disable* power-management).

That would be the ideal method because it tracks down the actual *cause* of the setting reverting. Unfortunately that only *finds* the cause; actually fixing it may not be easy or even possible. For example, Windows may automatically revert it on shutdown, or more likely, sets it to the default during boot up when it detects hardware.

## Defining “Device”; Check USB Port

Incidentally, are you plugging the drive into different USB ports? As far as Windows is concerned, a “known device” is a *pairing* of **device+port**, so if you have previously plugged a device into port A and let Windows install drivers for it, then you later plug the save device into port B, Windows will see it as a new device and (re-)install drivers for it along with the *default settings*. Therefore, you must re-set all settings when you plug it into a new port. After that, Windows should remember the settings for both the new and old port. You may want to plug your drive(s) once into each USB port and configure them so that you can be sure they are all configured in the future no matter which port you plug them into. (The same goes for drive letters, but those tend to be a little less reliable due to the ephemeral nature of drive letters for removable volumes.

## Treating the Symptom

One way to prevent Windows from reverting the setting is to simply deny access to the setting. This requires using the registry-editor which can be risky if you aren’t careful, so take the usual backup precautions and double-check before making a change (especially when deleting anything—which you should not be doing here anyway).

1. First you’ll need to find the relevant device-ID:
2. Open the *USB Root Hub Properties* dialog for your hub in *Device Manager* (figure 1), then switch to the *Power Management* tab
3. Change the value of the `Allow to turn off` checkbox (it doesn’t matter to what, just *change* it), but do *not* click <kbd>**OK**</kbd> (figure 5)
4. Run Process Manager and set a filter (figure 6):
5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
6. Set for `Path`, `contains`, `DisableSelectiveSuspend`, `Include`
7. Click <kbd>**Add**</kbd>
8. Set another filter for `Operation`, `contains`, `setvalue`, `Include`
9. <kbd>**Add**</kbd>
10. Click <kbd>**OK**</kbd>
11. Clear the current capture (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>) and start (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) if it’s not already running
12. Switch back to the *Device Manager* dialog box and click <kbd>**OK**</kbd>
13. Switch back to Process Monitor and stop capture (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>)
14. Note down the four-digit device ID after the [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID) (figure 7); in this example, `0055`:

    ```
     HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{36FC9E60-C465-11CF-8056-444553540000}\0055\HcDisableSelectiveSuspend
    ```
15. Click the line in Process Monitor, the press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to open Regedit and navigate directly to the key (if that doesn’t work, then open Regedit and manually navigate to the key)
16. Configure the setting to what you want it to be one last time (un-check the box in the *Power Management* tab and click <kbd>**OK**</kbd>)
17. Now lock that setting in and block access to the key (figure 8):
18. Right-click the key in the left pane of Regedit
19. Select *Permissions*
20. Click <kbd>**Advanced**</kbd>
21. *Un*-check the `Inherit from parent` box, then click <kbd>**Copy**</kbd> and <kbd>**OK**</kbd>
22. Back in the regular (non-advanced) permissions dialog, click each of the groups and users listed in the top list and for each one, *un*-check the `Full Control` box in the bottom list

Now nobody, not you, not even the system itself will be able to modify the setting (but they can still read it), so it should always stay at what you set it before setting it to read-only. (If needed, you can restore write-access by removing the item-specific permissions in the *Advanced Security Settings* dialog and re-checking the `Inherit from parent` box.

Of course, you’ll need to reboot afterwards to make sure the setting sticks.

## Last Resort

If the drive is *still* shutting down, try setting `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\usb\DisableSelectiveSuspend` to `1` and making it read-only as above. This setting is not present in a normal system, [nor is it documented][4] like [HcDisableSelectiveSuspend][5] is (the only references to it are on community pages), but Windows does seem to query this value before `HcDisableSelectiveSuspend` (figure 7), so it is worth a shot.

## Sherlock Holmes

At this point, if you want, you can go back and diagnose the underlying problem instead of just treating the symptom. You can use the above filter to have Process Monitor log write-access to the registry entry during startup (*Options → Enable Boot Logging*) and during [shutdown][6] (which is [slightly trickier][7]) to find out exactly what is changing it. Then you can cross your fingers and hope there is a way to prevent it.

---

## Illustrations

**Figure 1**: Screenshot of USB hub in Device Manager

[image: Screenshot of USB hub in Device Manager]

**Figure 2**: Screenshot of power draws on a USB hub

[image: Screenshot of power draws on a USB hub]

**Figure 3**: Photo of a USB Y-adapter

[image: Photo of a USB Y-adapter]

**Figure 4**: Diagram of USB Y-adapter usage

[image: Diagram of USB Y-adapter usage]

**Figure 5**: Screenshot of Power Management tab of USB hub

[image: Screenshot of Power Management tab of USB hub]

**Figure 6**: Necessary Process Monitor filters

[image: Screenshot of required Process Monitor filters]

**Figure 7**: Screenshot of relevant registry entry in Process Monitor results

[image: Screenshot of relevant registry entry in Process Monitor results]

**Figure 8**: Flow-diagram of setting a registry key to read-only

[image: Flow-diagram of setting a registry key to read-only]

Comment: First of all, thanks for your awesome answer, it definitely is in _pole position_ for the bounty. I followed your advice, and even though I have discovered additional details, the problem is not solved yet. I edited my question accordingly, I hope you can gain additional information from my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Go into Device Manager, expand the tree list under "Universal Serial Bus Controllers," right click on the entry for the device, and select properties.

[image]

Go to the "Power Management" tab in the properties dialogue and uncheck the box for "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power."

[image]

If you're using a laptop, you may also need to go into your advanced power plan settings and disable the option that allows Windows to cut power to devices when they are not in use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm sorry if it was not clear from my question (I use Win 7 in Italian and I tried to translate on the fly), but that's exactly what I've been doing so far.

Comment: I edited my question. Thanks again, but it appears the solution is not this easy.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to edit your registry.

1. open regedit.exe and run as administrator.

   a) click start > then type regedit in the search box > 
     right click on regedit.exe > select "run as administrator
2. Uncollapse [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\

   a) right click on services > hover over "new" and select "key"

   b) enter "USB"

   c) Navigate to "USB" > right click on USB

   d) hover over "new" and select "DWORD (32-bit) Value

   e) change the defaut value to "DisableSelectiveSuspend"

   f) Select DisableSelectiveSuspend > click "Edit">"Modify"

   g) under "Value data:"> change the 0 to a 1 > click okay.
3. Reboot your computer.  Your problem should be solved.

If you are uncomfortable editing your registry.  You can open notepad and cut and paste the text below into notepad and save the file with any name, say "temp.reg" it must have the ".reg" extension and not a ".txt" extension.  If you save the file in your "Documents" folder then you need to double click on the file from windows explorer and the registry values will be created for you.  Here is the text to paste into notepad, include everything between the lines.

---

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\USB]
"DisableSelectiveSuspend\""=dword:00000001

---

If you use the .reg file method, reboot your computer and your problem should be solved.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to completely delete the driver and clear out stale USB information :

1. Goto Device Manager, open "Universal Serial Bus Controllers",
   right-click the USB Root Hub and choose Uninstall.
2. Use regedit to delete `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\FLUSB`.
   In case of permissions error see
   [How to take full control of Windows Registry keys](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-take-full-control-of-windows-7-registry-keys) (including the comments).
   The free utility [RegOwnit](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/regownit-take-full-control-windows-registry-keys) might help here (I myself never used it).
3. Reboot.

Create first a system restore point, just in case.

Another solution would be to use an older driver, which can be combined with the above procedure.

Here are two that I found :
[3.5.36.0,A01](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=32V81)
[Fresco Logic USB 3.0 Driver 3.5.93.0](http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/MOTHERBOARD/Others/Fresco-Logic-USB-30-Driver-35930.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple different power management schemes set up, but you have one selected (such as "Balanced" or "High Performance"). Windows is probably loading your power management scheme you have selected, and *there* you likely do not have the USB power management disabled.

In the start menu, type "edit power plan" and select the option for that which the start menu finds. There are some other ways to get to this window too, such as through the personalization settings where you set your screen saver.

Once you are there, you need to "Change advanced power settings."

Then go down to "USB Settings", then to "USB selective suspend setting," and change the setting *here*.

[Here is an article that someone else wrote about your problem. In it are similar instructions and pictures.](https://web.archive.org/web/20131109044933/http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/2013/11/fix-usb-root-hub-power-management-issue-windows-7/)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but although I'm not sure I mentioned here, that's the first thing I tried. It didn't work. Currently the only solution that works is the one I posted, with the Powershell script disabling the setting at login.